# Visual C Optimization differences between 2008 and 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have a fairly complex algorithm I'm building using both visual c 2008 and visual c 2010. The algorithm is producing bad output when I compile with optimization enabled in VC 2010 (specifically, /Og).

Building the same exact code in VC 2008 (with or without optimization) or in VC2010 without optimization produces an algorithm that behaves correctly.

I'm having a very hard time debugging the code with optimization enabled, and have been stuck on this for quite a while.  Does anyone know any differences in optimization across versions?

Comment: This typically happens when you're invoking undefined behavior. There's a distinct possibility you're doing something wrong, even if "it works" with another compiler.

Comment: Is the generated code slow, or does it produce wrong results? Your wording isn't entirely clear, and new optimizations bringing undefined behavior to attention isn't unheard of.

Comment: You might want to run your program through whatever the equivalent of valgrind is in the Windows world.

Comment: It produces wrong results.  THe code works on a number of other platforms including DSPs and ARMS.

Comment: Well, in this case, you should have some means of debugging it. Do it in parallel for both versions, comparing every function output, 'till you find the culprit. Oh, wait, don't tell me, you have 10k line functions, right? :)

Comment: Thank you I will try to accept more answers. I'm not too familiar with the culture of this website.

Comment: Mihai, debugging is not that simple with optimization enabled. I can't step through every line and check every variable because a lot of them are optimized out. Whole functions are inlined and optimized out.

Comment: debugging does not just mean stepping through the code with a debugger. Add printfs, add assertions, place checks in the code to double check your assumptions. Create statistics within the code that you dump out at the end or at various points. Place probes in the code to verify each step/function/block/iteration/etc.. Gradually narrow it down so you'll find the point where the error occurs. Compilers are generally well tested and produces correct code for billions and billions of lines of code. It is almost always _your_ code that's wrong, not the compiler.

Comment: You say it works on other platforms including DSPs and ARMs - can you be more specific about on what platform(s) it doesn't work?  Is it one machine, or many machines (different processors, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a compiler bug, but you should try /Wall to enable all the warnings and fix all of them. There are also runtime checks like /RTCu (Uninitialized local usage checks) which you can use to isolate the problem. Also inspect all the type castings in your code to make sure they are legit.